# Why automatic calculation turned off by VBA macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code that turns off automatic calculation and i can't find a reason why is doing this. I use office 2016 and previously was using 2007 noticed back then that was going to manual but didn't know from which macro now i located the one that triggers the change but still don't know why. Any help on clarifying this will be much appreciated.

```
Public Sub editAllSheets()
'
'
'
    Dim myResult As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim WS As Worksheet

    myResult = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to edit all sheets in this workbook?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Edit Workbook?")
    If myResult = vbNo Then Exit Sub

       On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

            For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            WS.Activate
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
             editingProperties WS
             Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                Next WS
            Sheets.Select

            MsgBox "Please note:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. All the sheets are selected." & vbNewLine & "2. Proceed with print preview to view and print all reports." & vbNewLine & "3. To print preview or print only 1 report of this workbook you need to click on a different sheet to deselect all.", vbInformation, "Process Completed!"

        Exit Sub '<--- exit here if no error occured
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox "Sorry, an error occured." & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"

    End Sub

    Private Sub editingProperties(WS As Worksheet)

Dim columnsToDelete As Range

With WS
       .Columns("A:F").UnMerge

    Set columnsToDelete = Application.Union(.Columns("B:C"), _
                                            .Columns("F:K"), _
                                            .Columns("P:R"), _
                                            .Columns("V:W"))
        columnsToDelete.Delete

       .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
       .Range("A1:B2").Merge

   End With


     With WS.PageSetup
            .PrintArea = ""
            .PrintTitleRows = ""
            .PrintTitleColumns = ""
            .LeftHeader = ""
            .CenterHeader = ""
            .RightHeader = ""
            .LeftFooter = ""
            .CenterFooter = ""
            .RightFooter = ""
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .Zoom = False
           .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = 1

        End With
    End Sub
```

In the past, I used the below code to make macros faster but I notice a change from automatic calculation to manual without running anything so I deleted not sure if it's still related. Any help on solving this will be much appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Sub OptimizeVBA(isOn As Boolean)
    Application.Calculation = IIf(isOn, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
    Application.EnableEvents = Not(isOn)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Not(isOn)
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = Not(isOn)
End Sub

'Some macro
Sub ExampleMacro()
    OptimizeVBA True
    'Your code here
    OptimizeVBA False
End Sub
```

Comment: You may like to take a look at this thr3ead: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/the-calculation-option-keeps-switching-from-auto/2ed29346-b946-4aaf-9c19-83911eea812e The argument there is that if the first workbook opened during a session has calculation set to manual all others will inherit this setting. So, you should look at other workbooks which turn off automatic calculation and make sure it is turned on again before they close.

Comment: @Variatus i used to have a macro that turns off automatic calculation but I deleted it and now i have a new computer and move the personal macro workbook to the new pc but I've checked and the macro that use to turn off automatic calculation is not there because I've deleted before moving to the new pc. So my question is why is still happening ?

Comment: @Variatus  
Is there a reason why the `Sheets.Selec` line will trigger the automatic calculation to manual? I have recompile and no errors and debug it and when the code hits `Sheets.Select` it automatically changes to manual now why is that? I've commented out the line and the calculation mode remains automatic but i don't know the reason why it does that.

Comment: Not everything you delete is gone. To clean out a VBA project, export all code (use VBE's export function), make a copy of the workbook's sheets in an xlsx file, completely delete the xlsm file. Then import the code back into the xlsx file and save as macro-enabled. This will remove any hidden backups of past code snippets.

Comment: Another thought would be to investigate what `Sheets.Select` implies: how many sheets and what is on those sheets. In theory the implication could be an amount of calculation that can't be handled or doesn't need to be handled or involves data on other workbooks (including deleted ones) that might have (had) automatic calculation turned off. There is a lot of scope in this. `Sheets.Select` doesn't have many good reasons why it should be necessary.

Comment: @Variatus is it better if i export everything and delete the personal macro workbook and creat a new one? Will that solve the problem and import everything back again?

Comment: @Variatus The code above is in the personal macro workbook i just open the excel file from email run the above code print the reports and then close excel. There is no save on the hdd also this sheets doesn't contain any formulas what so ever so I don't release understand why it goes to manual when code hits the 'Sheets.Select'. Don't know what to do I've commented out that code and seems that it's working fine but that doesn't solve my problem. If anyone has any other ideas i can try to fix this i will also try  your approach at home and will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Yes. The old Wb must be deleted, and the new Wb must be created from a Wb which never had any code in it.

Comment: What does `Sheets.Select` do? I am proceeding from the thought that selecting all or many sheets might disable auto-calc by design, at least under some circumstances. If so, it should be re-enabled equally automatically when the sheets are released. Can you try that? But before going there I wonder if `Sheets.Select` can be avoided altogether. What's the purpose of this command within the context of your macro?

Comment: @Variatus I guess it can be avoided it just selects all sheets in the workbook so i can print preview all and then print all sheets instead of doing one by one. But can someone test this and let me know if this is the case. Because with it does this and I don't know whether it's something from the macro or this is how excel behaves. The file that I'm formatting it's just a report that i need just to print but it's not the way i need it to print as it's in portrait and the margins are not right and I don't need all the columns so i just edit it a little. No formulas involved.

Comment: @Variatus Just tried deleting everything and creating from scratch I've deleted the personal macro workbook and created from scratch but it does the same thing. Still, the problem is there and it's the same line that triggers the change to manual. Any other ideas that I can try??? And tried setting it back to automatic but it's not working for me.

Comment: Isn't it true that your Personal Web is invisible? I don't know if you can select invisible worksheets. This thought raises also the question of which Wb's sheets are being selected and whether Sheets = Worksheets in that Wb.

Comment: Create a loop which (a) selects each worksheet (sheet) in turn and see if any one of them triggers the anomality. Then extend the code to (b) add one sheet at a time to the simultaneous selection. See at which point the anomality occurs. Then try changing the sequence. You might be able to identify one sheet that causes the pb.

Comment: @Variatus Yes the personal macro workbook is hidden I just only want to select all worksheets in the active workbook.

Comment: @Variatus I've managed to solve my problem you were right basically if you manually select all sheets and then go to settings under formula excel changes automatically to manual and after you deselect sheets it will revert it back to automatic. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just salved my problem that I was facing with excel changing to manual from automatic calculation with @Variatus help. The problem is if you go and right click and select all worksheets excel automatically changes to manual but as soon as you right click and `ungroup sheets` this will change back to `automatic calculation`. So I've change my code to select the first sheet to deselect all sheets at the end of my code and have only one sheet active so the calculation is back to automatic. Also change from selecting all sheets to `Worksheets.PrintOut preview:=True` that will have the same effect but it's much clear the intention of the code. So need to be careful when selecting multiple worksheets to later deselect them otherwise it will create a problem down the line messing up the calculation from automatic to manual. Thank you for all your help.

```
Option Explicit
 Public WS As Worksheet

    Public Sub editAllSheets()
'
'
    Dim myResult As VbMsgBoxResult

    myResult = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to edit all sheets in this workbook?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Edit Workbook?")
    If myResult = vbNo Then Exit Sub

       On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

            For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            WS.Activate
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
             editingProperties WS
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                Next WS

            MsgBox "Please note:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "1. You will be redirected to print preview all your reports." & vbNewLine & "2. Proceed with printing reports.", vbInformation, "Process Completed!"

         Worksheets.PrintOut preview:=True

         Sheets(1).Select

        Exit Sub '<--- exit here if no error occured
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
        MsgBox "Sorry, an error occured." & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"

    End Sub

    Private Sub editingProperties(WS As Worksheet)

Dim columnsToDelete As Range

With WS
       .Columns("A:F").UnMerge

    Set columnsToDelete = Application.Union(.Columns("B:C"), _
                                            .Columns("E:J"), _
                                            .Columns("N:P"), _
                                            .Columns("T"))
        columnsToDelete.Delete

       .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
       .Range("A1:B2").Merge

   End With


     With WS.PageSetup
            .printArea = ""
            .PrintTitleRows = ""
            .PrintTitleColumns = ""
            .LeftHeader = ""
            .CenterHeader = ""
            .RightHeader = ""
            .LeftFooter = ""
            .CenterFooter = ""
            .RightFooter = ""
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = 1

        End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This Macro runs perfectly without turning off calculations.

If these functions are used within a loop that opens other books, then Variatus his comment is correct - It's a setting at application level, so all books opened within the same Application instance will indeed be affected if there's a workbook that executes code that includes `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` when opened

A workaround is to instantiate a seperate object as "New Application" and use that one to open additional workbooks. Example code:

Instead of:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Somepath\somefile.xlsm")
```

Use:

```
Dim xlApp as Application
Dim wb as Workbook

Set xlApp = New Application

Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("Somepath\somefile.xlsm")
'Do stuff 

wb.Close
xlApp.Close
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

The alternative is to store the current setting in a variable and reset it at the very end of execution:

```
'At the very beginning:
Dim calcSetting as Integer
calcSetting = Application.Calculation

'Do all execution

'At the every end:
Application.Calculation = calcSetting
```

Comment: i used to have a macro that turns off automatic calculation but I deleted it and now i have a new computer and move the personal macro workbook to the new pc but I've checked and the macro that use to turn off automatic calculation is not there because I've deleted before moving to the new pc. So my question is why is still happening ?

Comment: In any case it's not because of anything in the code you posted.

Comment: So any ideas on how to fix it because I tried every macro in the personal macro workbook and every time i run the above code is changes to manual. There is an email I received with this file that i need to edit and print this file is not saved on the pc so I just open check to see if the workbook is automatic and it is i run the above code go back check and it's manual i change back to automatic and print the file and quit excel. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Do you have any event code that might trigger? (Worksheet_change and such?)

Comment: Check your VBE settings. It might be that you have to recompile the personal macro workbook if compile on demand was turned off for that project. Other than that try stepping through the code with F8 to see if something unexpected executes. Since there's nothing wrong with what you posted it's guess work for me.

Comment: Is there a reason why the `Sheets.Select` will trigger the automatic calculation to manual? I have recompile and no errors and debug it and when the code hits `Sheets.Select` it automatically changes to manual now why is that?

Comment: In the past i used the below code to make macros run faster but i notice that excel started acting funny jumping from automatic calculation to manual so i deleted the code so now it should be working ok but it's not.
`Sub OptimizeVBA(isOn As Boolean)
    Application.Calculation = IIf(isOn, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
    Application.EnableEvents = Not(isOn)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Not(isOn)
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = Not(isOn)
End Sub
 
'Some macro
Sub ExampleMacro()
    OptimizeVBA True
    'Your code here
    OptimizeVBA False
End Sub`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146692/discussion-between-quicksilver-and-rik-sportel).